# How can I use awk to display some certain fields in a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a text file like this:

```
1 http 2 3 4 5 
2 dns 3 4 
3 ftp 3 4 5 6 8
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
http 2 3 4 5 
dns 3 4 
ftp 3 4 5 6 8
```

Node that I just want to omit the first column in that file and the fields number in a certain line is not fixed.

Can I accomplish this goal using `awk`?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use cut: `cut -d' ' -f2-`.

Edit: If you have to use awk, try `awk '{$1=""; print $0}'`

Comment: I'd also recommend using `cut` for this instead of awk

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe?

```
awk '{$1 =""; print }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the the field separators remaining in place, you can do this:

```
awk '{$1=""}1' filename
```

(Assuming filename is where you stored your data)

Answer (score 0):

Drats, I was going to give you an Awk solution, then recommend `cut`. It looks like others have beaten me to the punch.

However, I see no `sed` solution yet!

```
$ sed -n `s/^[^ ][^ ]*//p` yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^..//g' your_file
```

above should work based on the condition that the first field is always of a single character.

or in perl:

```
perl -pe 's/^[^\s]*\s//g' your_file
```